# Crontab runs shell that opens a jar - jar opens then closes within seconds

Tags: java, shell, jar, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a project that includes a series of data-logging sensors that send all data back to a CSV file through a Java application.  When run manually, both the .jar file and the .sh file will open the application and log the data without issue.

At this point, I need to restart the program each morning at 6AM in order to segment the CSV files into 1 day chunks.

Here's an example of the shell script I'm using:

`#!/bin/bash 
cd /home/pi/Desktop/Weights/410510/
sudo java -jar weight.jar`

And here's what I've been using in Crontab:

```
0 6 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/./start410510 >/tmp/file_name.log 2>&1
```

I added the log file output for debugging.  The program will run, and even log 1 data point on occasion, then close immediately.  The program is closed manually with user intervention on the keyboard or a physical exit of the terminal.  **Is it possible that crontab is inputting something that's causing the program to close?**

Here's the section of the program that allows it to close:

```
        System.out.print("\n\nPress any key to close...\n\n");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        }
          catch (IOException ex) {}
```

The output should look something like this, but with an entire 24 hours worth of data points:

```
  pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop $ sudo java -jar weight.jar
Waiting for the Phidget Bridge to be attached...
Phidget Information
====================================
Version: 102
Name: Phidget Bridge 4-input
Serial #: 410510
# Bridges: 4
Setting the enable state of bridge 0 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 0 to 8
Setting the enable state of bridge 1 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 1 to 8
Setting the enable state of bridge 2 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 2 to 8
Setting the enable state of bridge 3 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 3 to 8
Setting the data rate to 1000


Press any key to close...

2015-08-27 11:39:29.05,1,7.6E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:29.252,2,0.002682

2015-08-27 11:39:29.46,3,-0.001937

2015-08-27 11:39:29.836,0,-5.36E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:30.044,1,8.2E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:30.252,2,0.002563

2015-08-27 11:39:30.468,3,-0.001922

2015-08-27 11:39:30.836,0,-4.77E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:31.044,1,7.3E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:31.252,2,0.002638

2015-08-27 11:39:31.468,3,-0.001952

2015-08-27 11:39:31.836,0,-4.32E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:32.044,1,7.3E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:32.252,2,0.002667

2015-08-27 11:39:32.468,3,-0.001878

2015-08-27 11:39:32.836,0,-4.92E-4

2015-08-27 11:39:33.044,1,6.41E-4



Turning off Phidget Bridge
```

Instead, when the program runs through Crontab, the output of the log file is this:

```
 pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ more file_name.log
Waiting for the Phidget Bridge to be attached...
Phidget Information
====================================
Version: 102
Name: Phidget Bridge 4-input
Serial #: 410510
# Bridges: 4
Setting the enable state of bridge 0 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 0 to 8
Setting the enable state of bridge 1 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 1 to 8
Setting the enable state of bridge 2 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 2 to 8
Setting the enable state of bridge 3 to true
Setting the gain of bridge 3 to 8
Setting the data rate to 1000


Press any key to close...

2015-08-27 09:16:03.086,2,-1.94E-4


Turning off Phidget Bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a Java program interactively, the standard input is the console. If the user has not entered any data, then any read operations wait for user input and become blocked. This is because the stream is *open*, but doesn't have data yet.

This means you can use a read from standard input (`System.in`) as a way to wait.

But when you run a program in cron, non-interactively, `System.in`, the standard input, is not bound to a console. It is bound to a zero-byte stream (or a stream that has certain information that the cron entry supplies, but that's irrelevant at the moment).

When you have a zero-byte stream, it means that `System.in.read()` is not going to wait. It returns immediately with a value of -1, indicating that the stream end was reached.

This means that if you used `System.in.read()` for waiting in interactive mode, it won't work in non-interactive mode.

You'll need to find another way to stop the job when you run it from `cron`, and use a sleep loop or some other waiting mechanism to cause the program to wait until that "stop" event happens.

As a simple example, if you want the program to stop after it worked for a certain amount of time, say 8 hours, you can use:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep( 8L * 60L * 60L * 1000L ); // Sleep for 8 hours
} catch ( InterruptedException e ) {}       // Interrupt means stop execution.
// ... code that cleans up and stops the program
```

---

Note that it's probably not a good idea to tell the program to wait for 24 hours and have cron start a new one after 24 hours, because there is a high chance that the old execution and the new execution will either have a small interval when *both* are running (and then they might vie for the sensors), or a small interval when *neither* is running (and then nobody is listening to the sensors.)

It's better to design the program so that it runs indefinitely, and has a timer that rolls the log file every 24 hours, and not run it from cron at all.